# AIMD: Total number of packets sent

Tags: congestion

While answering to the quizz 4-3 of the great *Introduction to Computer Networking* (Stanford Lagunita), I found myself unable to explain the answer of one of the questions:

> Consider a long flow being transmitted in 1 kB packets by a transport protocol that (only) uses AIMD to control the window size. Initially, the window size is 10 kB. Every time the window opens to 20 kB, the last packet in the window is dropped, which is detected exactly after one round-trip time, and retransmitted.
>
> Q1: How many packets are sent up to and including the first packet that is dropped?
>
> Q2: How many packets are sent in total up to and including the second packet that is dropped? Hint: The second round will be the same. Don’t forget about the retransmitted packet.

Answers:

> Q1: 10 packets can be sent immediately. When the 10 are acknowledged, 11 packets are sent, then 12, then 13, …. until 20 packets are sent of which one is dropped. i.e. Sum (10 to 20) = 100 + 10 + sum (1..10) = 165 packets.
>
> Q2: The window is halved to 10kB again after the packet drop and starts again, sending the same number of packets plus the retransmitted one. i.e. 165 + 165 = 330 packets. (Note: the previously noted answer was 331, which is incorrect.)

While the answer for Q1 seems perfectly logical to me, it is not the case for Q2. My guess was 331, because of the first 165 packets sent, then the retransmission, and then the next batch of 165 packets.

In which way is 331 wrong ? Is the retransmission integrated to the next batch of packets ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the retransmission is integrated into the next batch of packets. For example:

1. RTT 1: Packet 1
2. RTT 2: Packets 2, 3
3. RTT 3: Packets 4, 5, **6 (X: Packet 6 is dropped**)
4. RTT 4: Packet 6 <-- *Packet resent because it was **dropped** last round*
5. RTT 5: Packets 7, 8
6. *etc., etc...*

This visualization should help you understand why the amount of packets sent in both the first and second rounds is identical:

[image: TCP Congestion Performance]

*Source: http://www.potaroo.net/ispcol/2005-06/faster.html*

Comment: You're answer has a window size of 1. In the question's scenario, RTT 1 sends 1..10, RTT 2 sends 11..22 and so on.

Comment: The AIMD algorithm would run the same way (a scaled up version of my example) in the second round: you'd send 10 packets (as a result of the window size being cut in half) which _includes_ the one that was dropped, until you reached 20, then another drop, and so on...

In the first 10 packets sent in the second round, you wouldn't add on an additional packet because then you'd be sending 11 packets, violating the algorithm. You'd simply send 10, then 11, then 12, ... , 20 until another drop. The calculation would be the same.

See the figure I attached in my answer above for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The dropped packet that is retransmitted becomes part of the second batch - it is not retransmitted separately.